# Material UI GridTile doesn't display actionIcon without title

Tags: css, reactjs, overlay, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI GridList to display some pictures in my React app. I'd like to have an IconButton on top of the image in my GridTile component. I can accomplish this by passing the button to the `actionIcon` prop. But it only shows up if I also pass a `title` prop. Looks like this when (`title='image'`):

[image]

Without the `title` prop, the overlay doesn't show. Passing `title=''` and `title={null}` both have the same result.

Is there any other way to have an IconButton on top of the image in a GridTile? My goal is to end up with something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridTile` component displays the overlay and `actionIcon` only if `title` evaluates to `true` (as of this writing, you can see that test around [line 200 of the source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/GridList/GridTile.js)). `null`, `undefined`, and an empty string all test out to `false`, which is why you're not seeing the overlay appear when you're using those values.

One workaround is to provide a `title` that has no impact on display but is not `false`, like a space (`' '`). For example, the following tile will have an overlay and visible `actionIcon` but effectively no title:

```
<GridTile
  key={tile.img}
  title={' '}
  actionIcon={<IconButton><StarBorder color="white" /></IconButton>}
>
```

As far as I know, this is the only possible fix in material-ui v0 (short of implementing this feature yourself and submitting a pull request). For a better, more elegant solution, you're going to have to look towards material-ui v1.

Material-ui v1 has a `GridListTileBar` component which controls the display of the overlay, icon, and title. This gives you fine grained control over what to display, so that you can implement your desired behavior with no workarounds.

However, I know that a full transition to v1 (which has a lot of breaking changes) can be daunting. If you want to transition only partially, you can [always install the two versions side by side](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7195#issuecomment-314547601). This will allow you to use the newest `GridList` and all of those features without having to change too much in the rest of your app.